# Implementation of table in table database sqlite android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want to have table as a value in my sqlite like below:
[image]

I searched about it and couldn't find anything appropriate and related.
any way to implement it in different kind of structure? 
the table I want to build in sqlite is far bigger than my example and I just want table in table structure in android sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just build a relational Database, with multiple tables as per your requirements and establish relationships between them as you need.
This link will give a nice kick-start http://www.quackit.com/database/tutorial/relational_database_design.cfm

Comment: Look up Foreign Keys/Fields.

Comment: Here are some useful links for learning SQLite
1.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/
2.  http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/

Comment: hey can you plz explain some more about relational databases. I read about it and couldn't find something relevant to the type of table I want to implement.